# How to pass the scanner number to an ArrayList

Tags: java

My method is working fine !!  I am trying to get the information from the user instead of putting the numbers myself as i did in my code.. is there a way that i can get pass the numbers without storing them in different variables! thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Interleave {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Interleave program! ");
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print("how many number for array 1:= ");
        int array1 = console.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1; i++) {
            System.out.print("please enter nubmers := ");
            int num = console.nextInt();
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a1.add(10);
        a1.add(20);
        a1.add(30);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("how many number for array 2:= ");
        int array2 = console.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < array2; i++) {
            System.out.print("please enter nubmers := ");
            int num2 = console.nextInt();
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a2.add(4);
        a2.add(5);
        a2.add(6);
        a2.add(7);
        a2.add(8);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(a1);
        System.out.println(a2);

        interleave(a1, a2); //parameters

        System.out.println(a1);


    }//end of main
    public static void interleave(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        int sizeList1 = list1.size();//size of array
        int sizeList2 = list2.size();//size of array

        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //


        for (int index = 0; index < list1.size(); index++)// copy elements ferom list 1
            temp.add(index, list1.get(index));


        for (int index = 0; index < list2.size(); index++)// copy elements ferom list 2
            temp.add(index, list2.get(index));


        int tempSize = temp.size(); //get temporary array size

        temp.clear(); //clear tepm array


        if (list1.size() > list2.size()) {
            for (int index = 0, list1Index = 0, list2Index = 0;
            index < sizeList1;
            index = index + 2, list1Index++, list2Index++ )
            {
                temp.add(index, list1.get(list1Index));
                temp.add(index + 1, list2.get(list2Index));
            }


            for (int index = 2 * list2.size(),
            list2Count = list2.size();
            index < tempSize; list2Count++, index++ )
            temp.add(index, list1.get(list2Count));

            list1.clear(); // clear list 1

            for (int index = 0; index < temp.size(); index++)
                list1.add(index, temp.get(index));
        } else {
            for (int index = 0, list1Index = 0, list2Index = 0;
            index < sizeList2;
            index = index + 2, list1Index++, list2Index++ )
            {
                temp.add(index, list1.get(list1Index));
                temp.add(index + 1, list2.get(list2Index));
            }

            for (int index = 2 * list1.size(),
            list1Count = list1.size(); index < tempSize;
            list1Count++, index++ )
            temp.add(index, list2.get(list1Count));


            list1.clear();

            for (int index = 0; index < temp.size(); index++)
                list1.add(index, temp.get(index));
        }


    }//end of interleave


}//end of class
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an ArrayList of integers
2. every time you need to add a number, call `mylist.add(console.nextInt())`
3. Call `mylist.clear()` when you're done, or set it to a new ArrayList.

Just be careful of the various exceptions that may be thrown and try catching them so that the user has to retype the number until it is valid.